# How to interpret AWS Device Farm Thread Count?

Tags: android, performance-testing, aws-device-farm

[image]

Can somebody help/does anybody know how to interpret the threads count that AWS Device Farm reports?
I looked through the report and did not understand why it suddenly jumped from 0 thread into 71 threads just in 1 second.

Answer (score 0):

We are using adb shell /proc/pid/stat where pid is the the process id for the app  you uploaded to populate the thread count information.

You need to investigate the logcat logs and application code to find the reasons for consumption.